# JavaFX - how to set visible vertical Scrollbar to always in TableView?

Tags: javafx-2

I have `JavaFX` 2.2 `TableView` component and need to `Scrollbar` set visible always.So how can I set visible Scrollbar to always in `TableView` using `JavaFx` css or as a `TableView` property in fxml?

Comment: Maybe this can help, it's for a ListView but might work for TableView as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412933/always-show-vertical-scrollbar-for-javafx-listview

Comment: Ref this solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321167/vertical-menu-for-configuration-panel/18327570#18327570